# Decrypting a Password Protected Zipped File using DotNetZip C#

Tags: c#, encryption, dotnetzip

I m trying to extract a zipped file through `DotNetZip`. The file is `encrypted` with a password and needs to be either reset or removed. I used `ExtractAll` method but received exception:

> BadPasswordException was unhandled, the password didnot match.

My code is below:

```
using (Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zip = Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Read(source_file))
{
    zip.Password = "1234";
    zip.ExtractAll(dest_path, Ionic.Zip.ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: use the right password?

Comment: no i m trying to extract as if i dont know the password.

Comment: Well, without the password, it won't work. You'll have to crack it somehow. The entire point of having a password on it is that you can't extract the files without it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation use

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(ExistingZipFile))
{
    ZipEntry e = zip["TaxInformation-2008.xls"];
    e.ExtractWithPassword(BaseDirectory, Password);
}
```

http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/Index.html